# Problem using httpClient.PostAsync Result = "{Not yet computed}"

Tags: c#, rest

im trying to upload a file using POST, normally it works well and i have no problem but there is a case where the file has to be separated in various parts to get uploaded (its something that is made in the API side so the method in my code for upload the file is the same than the normal upload) when i try to do this i recieve this response `Id = 3129, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"` i think is because this response takes longer and maybe my side doenst wait until is ready
this is the code

```
var httpResponse2 = httpClient.PostAsync(url + "/" + api + "/" + coin + "/transaction/multiple-transaction-woc", content);
responseContent2 = await httpResponse2.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

when it reach `responseContent2` it breaks because Result is null

ive tryed `var httpResponse2 = httpClient.PostAsync(url + "/" + api + "/" + coin +"/transaction/multiple-transaction-woc", content).wait;` but it doenst work and using await break it too.

when i use postman works just fine.

Sorry for my english and thank you for any help.

Comment: `await httpClient.PostAsync`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should await the actual HTTP call first, and then process any content asynchronously as well.

Your final code should look a bit like this:

```cs
var httpResponse2 = await httpClient.PostAsync(url + "/" + api + "/" + coin + "/transaction/multiple-transaction-woc", content);
responseContent2 = await httpResponse2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: at the end i use `var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(url + "/" + api + "/" + coin + "/transaction/multiple-transaction-woc", content).ConfigureAwait(false);` and `responseContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` now it works just fine, Thank You!